# What is mod(a,b)?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

I was reading the AKS Primality Test. [AKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test).
I could not understand the line :

$(x - a)^{n} = (x^{n} - a) \pmod{(n,x^{r}-1)}$

What is $\mod{(a,b)}$ in it ?

Comment: The $r$ is defined in the algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Algorithm

Comment: @ASHISH My answer is incorrect; please accept Daniel Fisher's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(a,b)$ is a common notation for $\gcd(a,b)$. So the line
$$(x-a)^n\equiv (x^n-a)\pmod{(n,x^r-1)}$$
means the same thing as
$$(x-a)^n\equiv (x^n-a)\pmod{m}$$
where $m=\gcd(n,x^r-1)$.

Comment: Actually, here $(a,b)$ is the ideal generated by the two elements $a$ and $b$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $x$ is an indeterminate, $\gcd (n,x^r-1) = 1$ for $r > 0$.

Comment: Well, but $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID...

Comment: @Tomas And that's why there's a difference between $\pmod{(a,b)}$ and $\pmod{(\gcd(a,b))}$.

Comment: Exactly! My comment was directed to Zev, not to you. We totally agree :)

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, thank you for your correction. I didn't look at the Wikipedia page for context, and just assumed that $x$ was an integer. I can't delete my answer while it's accepted, but I've asked the OP to accept your answer instead.

Comment: What about simply correcting the answer? That would be the fastest way to replace erroneous information with correct information. Of course it's problematic to substantially change an accepted answer, but I think it's acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at a congruence in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. For the integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ whose primality shall be determined, a specific value $r$ is determined, with the property that $n$ is prime if and only if the congruence

$$(x-a)^n \equiv x^n-a \pmod{I}$$

holds (for all $a$ in some sufficiently small set), where

$$I = (n, x^r-1)$$

is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by the two elements $n$ and $x^r-1$.

Considering the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/(n)$, that is equivalent to the congruence

$$(x-a)^n \equiv x^n - a \pmod{(x^r-1)}$$

in $R[x]$, which may be a more familiar form.